# How to avoid 429 on nodejs loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, axios

Work on NODEJS. Need to collect data from API, To execute API requires the Id and response the result.

```
const companies=[1,2,3,4,5,....1000];

    for (let company of companies) {
       let{data} =axios.get("API url"+company);
    }
```

above code run perfectly but after a while showing the error "**Request failed with status code 429"**

Comment: [429: Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)

Comment: if its your api then implement a single company lookup or multiple (post the array)

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, it's a third-party API, they have no batch service, need to fetch one by one.

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense. `axios.get` returns a promise. A promise doesn't have a `data` property. `let{data} =axios.get("API url"+company);` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `async` / `await`

You are actually issuing 1000 concurrent requests to the server. `axios` is asynchronous, and as such returns a promise. Which means that it will initiate the request but will not "wait" (or block execution) for the server to answer.

To avoid 429 "Too many requests" error you can, among other solutions, wait for a request to finish before initiating the next one. your code may look like this:

```
(async ()=> {
    const companies=[1,2,3,4,5,....1000];

    for (let company of companies) {
       let{data} = await axios.get("API url"+company);
    }
})();
```

Other notes:

- the destructuring of `data` from a promise (in your original code) is probably incorrect.
- with the nature of `async` functions, when called without `await` (e.g. from a regular function) it will `return` a promise upon the first `await`, and will continue to execute as data arrives.

Comment: After applying your first approach, nothing is executed  under the (async ()=> {})(); nothing is executed